# ScrollView and Navigation Bar ios9

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, ios9, navigationbar

I have a View Controller (named View2) embedded in a Navigation Controller.
In this view I have a ScrollView which covers all the view (including the navigation bar).

This View Controller is presented from another view with the call:

```
let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View2") as! View2
let modalStyle: UIModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
let nav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: view2)
nav.modalTransitionStyle = modalStyle
self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In my View2, I adjust the navigation bar to be translucent:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

But there is an issue, when View2 appears, the scrollview starts bellow the navigation bar. I have to tapp one time on the scrollview to see it auto-adjust at the top of the screen, over the navigation bar.

Any idea to fix it?

I want than the scrollview appears at the top of the screen, over the translucent navigation bar.

Thank you for your feedbacks,

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` on your view controller?

Another option would be to uncheck the option "Under Top Bar" in the view controller's attributes inspector in "Extend Edges".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` after having set my scrollview fix it. Thank a lot for the trick!